# Replace string with a regex containing a variable without macro

Tags: clojure

I need to delete some contents at the end of a string (eq_code) using Clojure.
I want to implement a regex initialized by a variable **(get-in vector [3 1])**.

Maybe macro would have helped me.

Here is the code :

```
(reset! atom_code (clojure.string/replace eq_code #(str (get-in vector [3 1])) ""))
```

The error is :

```
IllegalArgumentException Invalid match arg: project.core$interpreted_lang_while$fn__4457@7ac4b7c5  clojure.string/replace (string.clj:102)
```

Is there a way to replace a substring without using macro ?
For example using a function that return a regex.

Comment: Your code there passes an anon-function `#(str ...)` to `str/replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace

`replace` match parameter (second arg) can't be a function.
The solution is to construct the pattern from your dynamic value:

```
user> (def data [["a" "b"] ["c" "d"]])
#'user/data

user> (clojure.string/replace "mama" (re-pattern (get-in data [0 0])) "")
"mm"
```

and also: `vector` is the core function, so try not to shadow it by using it as a var name (though it's not actually what is wrong with your solution)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `vector` is a clojure function, and I am guessing that you have some data named `vector` that is causing the compiler confusion.

Could you please update your question with sample data and desired output?

Comment: Finally, I have found a workaround to my problem. I no longer need using (string/replace). Thanks you for your help.